# Removing image from button misplaces text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I remove the image of a button (by setting it to nil), it makes the text move to the bottom left of the button. Am I removing the image the wrong way or am I supposed to reposition the text after moving it? Or am I supposed to remove the text and set it back?

Setting the button image:

```
[self.photoButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.photoButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, -100.0, 10.0, 15.0)];
```

Before removing image:
[image: image 1]

Removing the button image:

```
[self.photoButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

After removing image:
[image: image 2]

I believe I see the problem now. I am setting UIEdgeInsets to something (forgot about that).

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code and some before and after pictures showing the problem (please crop the images showing only the affected button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both text and image on a UIButton they are adjusted so both of them ar visible, if you are just removing the text by default it should show in the center of button if you remove the image. It should not move it to bottom left.

Comment: When I set the image of the button, should I also remove the text (text is not supposed to be visible and when I add image it isn't). I'll update answer with code and images.

Comment: No you can have both text and image at the same time if its a normal UI button it adjusts automatically,

Comment: Yes default is UIEdgeInsetsZero, with all values set to zero.

Comment: So you will add this line after or just before removing the image [self.photoButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];